# Upgrading project java-7 to java-17 and tomcat-7 to tomcat-10

Tags: java, tomcat7, java-7, java-17, tomcat10

I am upgrading my project from
java-7 to java-17
and
tomcat-7 to tomcat-10

I am getting this two exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Servlet (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @f20570f; jakarta.servlet.Servlet is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @1ddc4ec2)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1071)

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/fileNotFound.jsp (line: [3], column: [0]) Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: [org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV]

my project structure

[image]

I tried all possible number of solution provided by many form but not solved.

Comment: It seems that you are using an older version of the Spring Framework (before 6.0) together with Tomcat 10.1. That doesn't work because Spring Framework before 6.0 requires the class `javax.servlet.Servlet`, but Tomcat 10.1 only provides `jakarta.servlet.Servlet`. You need to upgrade your Spring Framework version to 6.0.8